# pass variable to javascript method

Tags: javascript, variables, object, methods

I am having trouble passing values to methods of objects. I want to be able to pass a variable to an objects method when I call it however I cant seem to work out how this is done.

NOTE: I need to pass these values byRef however I am using strings to keep the example simple, in my actual code I am passing objects.

```
function makeObject(){
    var object = [ ];
    object.parameter1 = 0;
    object.parameter2 = "text";
    object.method = function (var1, var2){
        console.log(var1+" "+var2);
    }
    return object;
}

var myObject = makeObject();
```

This was how I expected it to work

`myObject.method("hello", "world");
//console returns "undefined undefined"`

I later read up that bind may be the answer but this does not seem to work

`myObject.method.bind("hello", "world");
//console returns "undefined undefined"`

Comment: I think you're mixing concepts here, plus `object` is not an actual object `{}` is an array `[]`. You're trying to make a constructor? If you read on `bind` you'll see that is not used like that, `bind` just changes the context of `this`.

Comment: you probably shouldn't be using the variable name object as it is a reserved word

Comment: Actually it should be working. And it works if you test it in console. You should use `{}`. Anyway arrays are objects too, so the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: You sample works perfectly fine. Please verify if you actually see an issue with code you've posted, if not - please edit it so it actually shows the issue.

Comment: thanks for all the comments / help, still struggling I will post back when I have exhausted the new info

Comment: Yeah this example does actually work, I should have checked that, seems I simplified the problem too much, at least this eliminates a few issues, thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is defining an array `[]`, not an object `{}`.  While you *should* be able to put methods onto an array just fine, I think something like this is what you're looking for

```
function makeObject(){
    var obj = { }; //an object literal
    obj.parameter1 = 0;
    obj.parameter2 = "text";
    obj.method = function (var1, var2){
        console.log(var1+" "+var2);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Also note that you can return your entire object inline:

```
function makeObject(){
    return {
      parameter1: 0,
      parameter2: "text",
      method: function (var1, var2){
        console.log(var1+" "+var2);
      }
   };
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GD4HE/)

---

Also, for the second part of your question, `bind` serves to *pre-set* the this value of a function, and also to curry parameters.  This is contrived, but for example:

```
var sayIt = function(y){
    this.say(y);
};

var obj = { 
   say: function(val){ console.log(val); } 
};
var sayThat = sayIt.bind(obj, "that");
sayThat();

//logs that to console.
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JvyKs/)

Comment: I have not solved my issue but you answer was the best, still trying to debug where my issue is as it is sveral levels deep in scope, might post a new question when I weed out the real issue